How can multiple WGSL sources be combined such that line numbers are properly reported?
I have organized my project so that some shared functionality is kept in separate .wgsl files. I can load them and dynamically compose them into a single string myself, but then the line reporting for WGSL errors is relative to the beginning of the composed string instead of to the beginning of the respective files.
How is it intended for this to be handled? I found some mention of "source maps" by searching online, but I'm using the C/C++ bindings for wgpu and I can't find any reference to this concept in the Rust docs or the structs exposed by the bindings.
How do I get correct line numbers?

When you create a shader module, you can add a sourceMap= argument.  This format of this argument is described here:
I've no idea if any implementation actually pays attention.

That's in JS; is this exposed in wgpu? And what on Earth is that mappings parameter doing? Does it have anything to do with line numbers, or can I ignore it?

The sourceMap parameter was removed. See spec. Something else may be added in the future

@gman. I notice that the spec has multiple versions.  Do you know if there is any sort of changelog so it's possible to see what's changed from one version to the next?

You can look at the github history. But as for sourceMap, the links above lead to why it was removed.
